# Flutter access variable in other dart file

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to access an instance of a `HeaderContainer` object inside another .dart file. The object is instantiated during startup before running `runApp();`. I have `WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();` at the beginning of `main.dart`.

My simplified main.dart:

```
class HeaderContainer {
  Header header;
  HeaderContainer({this.header});
  Header getHeader() {
    return header;
  }
}

void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  Header header = new Header();
  HeaderContainer headercontainer = new HeaderContainer(header: toc);
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      home: MyTabs(),
    ),
  );
}
```

My simplfifed other Dart file:

```
class _MeasureListState extends State<MeasureList> {
  @override

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.grey[300],
      body: Column(
          children: getWidgetList(),),
    );
  }
}

List<Widget> getWidgetList() {
Header toc = headercontainer.getHeader();
return toc.results.map((result) {
return MeasCard(result: result);
}).toList()

}
```

But when I try to access that object, I always get the error `The name 'header' isn't defined`. How do I fix that?

Comment: Please share a simplified code

Comment: ok, got it.hope you understand what I want to do here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make headerContainer variable static
so you can access it anywhere

Answer (score 1):

Use static keyword in the declatation of header object

static Header header = new Header();

And then access using HeaderContainer.header or classname.header